# Mobile & Credit cart Paybox Payment

Tags: android, ios, mobile, paypal, payment

I need to implement paybox on a mobile native app.
In fact, it is a web app build as native IOS & Android.

I would like tom implement paybox module for credit card.
But I am not sure it is relevant cause I could not find so much information about it.

I could imagine opening a iframe in my app with the paybox form so the user can enter his information ...
But I will not be able to manage the return.

Does anyone has a clue about the possibilities ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Take a look at [Braintree's v.zero](https://www.braintreepayments.com/v.zero) or [PayPal's Mobile SDK](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/mobile/mobile-sdk-overview/).

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
I'll manage it via classic html platform in iframe but I'll take a look at those solution.

Comment: @GeorgesAbitbol did you get a solution to integrate paybox on the a native (android or ios) apps?